# When user types "enter" in a <form> how to distinguish if the user is trying to submit or to select from autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried some suggestions like recording when user hits "down arrow" key, but it is not robust. When user hits down arrow and then uses mouse click to select from drop down autocomplete list then the method breaks.

Can you please tell me if there's a robust way to distinguish if the user's "enter" key event is trying to submit the form or select from drop down autocomplete?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if the user has a focus on the dropdown.

For example

```
 if ($("#yourdropdown").is(":focus"))
 {
    return false;
 }
```

this is done by jquery    [jquery Focus](http://api.jquery.com/focus/)

Comment: if you want to check ALL dropdowns, you can add a class or data- attribute for your items, and check on those attributes

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it is not "my drop down", it is browser's autocomplete implementation.

Comment: you can check on all input fields --> $("input").is(":focus)

Comment: I tried using if($("#MyInputTextBoxId").is(":focus")){alert('on focus');}, but the focus is on textbox even when the user is actually focusing on the drop down.